# Following code is giving runtime error in ideone but runs fine in eclipse and bash terminal

Tags: java

I am running a code to compute some `BigInteger` values in a String `ArrayList`. Computation is done outside the `ArrayList` and then added back to the list as a string.

The code runs fine through Ubuntu terminal and in Eclipse IDE, but gives a runtime error in [Ideone](https://www.ideone.com/8ZZvyR) and other online IDEs.

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader kb = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int T = Integer.parseInt(kb.readLine());
        for(int i = 0; i<T; i++){
            int N = Integer.parseInt(kb.readLine());
            ArrayList<String> L = new ArrayList();
            //int[] L = new int[N];
            for(int j = 0; j<N; j++){
                L.add(Integer.toString(j+1));
            }
            while(L.size()>1){
                BigInteger x = new BigInteger(L.get(0).substring(0));
                BigInteger y = new BigInteger(L.get(L.size()-1).substring(0));
                L.remove(0);
                L.remove(L.size()-1);
                BigInteger fin = new BigInteger("0");
                fin = fin.add(x);
                fin = fin.add(y);
                fin = fin.add(x.multiply(y));
                String finstring = fin.toString();
                L.add(finstring);
            }
            int r = 0;
            for(int j = 0; j<L.get(0).length(); j++) {
                r = (r * 10 + (int)L.get(0).charAt(j) - '0') % 100000007; 
            }
            System.out.println(r);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because how to properly 
use Ideone is not a suitable question for Stack Overflow

Comment: This crashes in any environment if you give the input as "1 4".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate the input into two lines in order to get them as separate values.

Change the input value from this:

```
1 4
```

to

```
1
4
```

See it working here: https://www.ideone.com/CkMCAn